# How to integrate android studio with bitbucket

Tags: android

I want to push my android studio project into bitbucket repository.any one suggest me how to integrate my android studio with bitbucket.

Comment: What is the problem? Seems like you didn't do at least basic research by your own ... Google query on *"bitbucket"* returns *"Bitbucket — **The Git** solution for professional teams"* ... android studio supports Git ... so again, where is the problem?

Comment: Keep it simple, use the command line.

Comment: Check this link to upload android project on BitBucket:- 

http://www.learnwithmindscript.in/blog/user/blog_details/3

Answer (score 1):

**Preferences > Plugins** , search for and install **Bitbucket Plugin** , 
Now under in VCS, you'll see bitbucket will be available for version controlling options.

Further i strongly recommend you to use **SourceTree** , a great tool to manage ur bitbucket repositories and projects, without touching VCS in android. You can simply import your project folder in SourceTree and continue working in Android Studio, all your changes will be tracked in sourceTree where you can do every operation (Branching,commits,merges) easily without commandline and annoying And. studio integrations

https://www.sourcetreeapp.com

Answer (score 0):

`download git Bash` 
1.make repository in Bit bucket
2.create new folder
3.clone into new folder
4.past code in new folder
`use following command to push project on git`
4.$ git add *
5.$ git commit -m "adding \project code"
6.$ git push origin master

Answer (score 0):

Get started with command line

**Existing project:**

Step 1: Switch to your repository's directory

```
cd /path/to/your/repo
```

Step 2: Connect your existing repository to Bitbucket

```
git remote add origin https://your_login@bitbucket.org/your_login/your_project_name.git
git push -u origin master
```

**Starting from scratch:**

```
git clone https://your_login@bitbucket.org/your_login/your_project_name.git
cd your_project_name
echo "# My project's README" >> README.md
git add README.md
git commit -m "Initial commit"
git push -u origin master
```